# How to get product category URL Key?

Tags: magento-1.8, category, category-products

How can I get the product category's URL Key?

I can get the category name by `$category->getName()` but it does not work if I use this `$category->getURLKey()`,

```
$categories = $_product->getCategoryCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('name');

foreach($categories as $category) {
    $productCategoryName = $category->getName();
    var_dump($category->getURLKey());
}
```

Return `null`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$categories = $_product->getCategoryCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
    ->addUrlRewriteToResult();
```

Then in your loop try using `getUrl()` method.

Comment: thanks but it return the hittp url, such as `http://localhost/mystore/bin/app/magento/en/wine/` instead of `wine`.

Comment: I did it with `->addAttributeToSelect('url_key')` and then `$category->getUrlKey()` then i get `wine` for instance. thanks!

Comment: Ah sorry, I read it wrong. Thought you needed a complete URL, not just URL key.

Comment: No worries. You have given me a very good hint for doing that! :-)